# How can I move a user defined split string function into a class with other basic math functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It takes three arguments from one string and splits them and returns the calculation. Should I give it its own class? Is there a way to add it to the rest of the class and functions that take two inputs? I'm trying to add it to this block but having trouble. The scalc function has strip formatting.

```
class calculator:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.Num1 = a
        self.Num2 = b
    def add(self):
        return self.Num1 + self.Num2
    def subtract(self):
        return self.Num1 - self.Num2
    def multiply(self):
        return self.Num1 * self.Num2
    def divide(self):
        return self.Num1 / self.Num2
    def allInOne(self):
            result = {
            "add": self.Num1 + self.Num2,
            "sub": self.Num1 - self.Num2,
            "mult": self.Num1 * self.Num2,
            "div": self.Num1 / self.Num2}
            return result
    def start(self):
        print('which calculation do you want to perform?''\n'
              '1: Add' '\n' '2: Subtract''\n'
              '3: Multiply' '\n' '4: Divide' '\n' '5: allInOne')
        choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
        switcher = {1: self.add(),
                2: self.subtract(), 
                3: self.multiply(), 
                4: self.divide(),
                5: self.allInOne()}
        function = switcher.get(choice)
        return function


a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
b = int(input("Enter another number: "))
function = calculator(a,b)
pass
print(function.start())##this is what I'm trying to add:
 
def scalc(p1):
    # p1 will be a string like this "N1, N2, operator"
    items = p1.split(",")
    operand1 = float(items[0].strip())
    operand2 = float(items[1].strip())
    operator = items[2].strip()
    if operator == "+":
        return sum1(operand1, operand2)
    elif operator == "-":
        return difference1(operand1, operand2)
    elif operator == "*":
        return product1(operand1, operand2)
    elif operator == "/":
        return quotient1(operand1, operand2)
```

Comment: Why are you using a class here in the first place? Do you need to store the 2 numbers before / after doing the calculation?

Comment: it's a homework assignment  to move all user defined functions from previous assignments into their own class.

Answer (score 1):

scalc() has four related functions: add, sub, mul, div.
So you certainly want to organize them together,
in their own module or their own class.
Often a `class` will prove convenient.

---

The current class constructor seems pretty disconnected
from scalc. Consider making it a no-args constructor
if you don't really need to store `num1` & `num2`.

---

Defining four functions, for a four function calculator,
is perfectly nice. It can offer a convenient place
to put debug breakpoint() / print() statements,
for example.

But consider using python's predefined functions,
such as [mul()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul).

---

An `if` statement is *one* way to dispatch
to the compute functions.
But notice that a `dict` can conveniently
do that, as well.

```
>>> from operator import add, sub, mul
>>> 
>>> d = {'+': add,  '-': sub,  '*': mul}
>>> 
>>> op = '+';  d[op](2, 3)
5
>>> op = '*';  d[op](2, 3)
6
```

---

Currently you have a bunch of methods in this class,
each accepting `self` as initial argument,
and enjoying access to the `num1` / `num2`
instance attributes.

If you delete your (no-arg) `__init__` constructor,
then the remaining methods could become
`@staticmethod`, with no initial `self` argument.
In other words, a class instance object
would carry no state.

At that point it would be simpler to express
the concept with a bunch of `def` functions,
deleting the `class` altogether.

---

Consider adhering to the
[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
community conventions.
So, initial capital on a class named `Calculator`,
and initial lowercase on e.g. `num1`.

---

EDIT

You wrote

> ```
>     if operator == "+":
>         return sum1(operand1, operand2)
> ```

(Let's ignore `all_in_one`, which isn't hooked up to anything.)

That implementation looks good to me.
I assume you *also* defined either

```
class Calculator:

    @staticmethod
    def sum1(x, y):
        return x + y
```

or simply

```
def sum1(x, y):
    return x + y
```

outside the class.

It does exactly what `operator.add` does,
and that's fine.
For one thing, it offers a convenient
spot for breakpoint() / print() debugging.

---

There is certainly not a need to write a
whole new class for the scalc function.

## tl;dr: You don't need state

In none of the variant bits of code I've seen
in this question have I seen a need for state.
That is, storing A & B, or num1 & num2,
in an object instance, is not necessary.

Why?

Because you always pass in those two numbers
in the args when you call add / sub.
Since the pair of numbers is available
from the args, we don't need e.g. `self.num1`.

Given that you don't need state, for your purposes
each of the three forms is pretty much identical:

```
class Calculator:

    def sum1(self, x, y):
        return x + y  # We're ignoring self, and that's OK.
```

or the `@staticmethod` above, or the `def` above.

Use the form you find most convenient.